# Binding PushPin Style Text to PushPin.Text

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I have a style for PushPin

```
<Style x:Key="PushPinStyle" TargetType="Maps:Pushpin">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="39"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>                      
               <Image Source="Assets/Point.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding Text}/>
                       </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And I want textblock to bind to pushpin.text

```
 public void AddPushpin(Location latlong, string title, string description, MapLayer layer,string pinText)
    {
        try
        {
            Pushpin p = new Pushpin()
               {
                   Tag = new Metadata()
                   {
                       Title = title,
                       Description = description
                   }
               };
       //
            p.Style =     this.Resources["PushPinStyle"] as Style;
            p.Text = pinText;                      //This should appear in pushpin on top of Image

            MapLayer.SetPosition(p, latlong);

            p.Tapped += PinTapped;

            layer.Children.Add(p);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }
```

But all i can see is image only .

How do i Bind  PushPin.text to TextBlock of style and show it above the image of style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of two.

```
<Style x:Key="PushPinStyle" TargetType="Maps:Pushpin">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="39"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Maps:Pushpin">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="Assets/Point.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

OR

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Comment: Text is not recognizable in{TemplateBinding Text}  , didn't work